# Using lib with split packages Java9 with maven

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, java-9

I want to use the boofcv and the openimaj libs in a modular javafx application which uses the java module system.

The problem is that both libs are using split packages and that is not allowed. I have now learned from the web that in java9 there is the cmd patch-modules which should merge the modules into one.

But how can I do this with maven ? The maven compiler throws "illegal argument" if I try to use "--patch-modules" as an argument.

Does anybody know how can I use maven with split packages ?

Comment: Could you share a reproducible example where you get the error?

Comment: Here is my pom.xml where https://github.com/lanthale/PhotoSlide/blob/94a398846e4f105b2679cdeb2d4680a196f3a417/PhotoSlide/pom.xml . I am using many libs but only openimaj is using split packages. As soon as moditect is creating the module descriptor it is failing with the issue from jdeps. If I add patch-module option to the maven-compiler it gaves the error message above.